# JIRA REST API Sprint Issue route - timeSpent and timeSpentSeconds don't match

Tags: json, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm currently using the JIRA REST API to retrieve the amount of time spent on a ticket in a project using the following route:

`/rest/agile/1.0/board/{boardId}/sprint/{sprintId}/issue`

Within one of the `issues`, I receive the following data relating to time:

```
 "timetracking": {
      "remainingEstimate": "9w 1d",
      "timeSpent": "4d",
      "remainingEstimateSeconds": 1324800,
      "timeSpentSeconds": 115200
    },
```

When converting the seconds to days, it results in 1.33333333 days, where as the `timeSpent` specifies 4 days.

Why does `timeSpent` and `timeSpentSeconds` not add up, and is there a way to resolve the issue to ensure that they do match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. As it turns out, it does not work on a 24 hour period, i.e. `1d` does not equal `86400`, but rather it works on hours spent on the project per day, in my case, `8h`. Therefore the seconds is `4 * 8` which equals `1.33333...` days.